# Trigger OnFormClosing() from MenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

I have a simple WinForm Application where I have defined an override for `OnFormClosing`, to be able to ask for an exit confirmation and close the sql connection.
 It looks like this:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (MessageBox.Show(this, "Really quit " + Application.ProductName + "?",
                     Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                     MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation))
        {
            case DialogResult.Yes:
                con.Close();
                Debug.WriteLine("Connection Closed");
                Debug.WriteLine("Exiting Application");
                Application.Exit();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately when I Close the form the "really-quit"-dialog pops up twice.
Why is this so?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in OnFormClosing() and then click first X button and later exit menu to check the call stacks for both calls and see from where all (which method(s)) the call to OnFormClosing() method is coming..

Comment: There was onother issue in my code, fixed the question. The really-quit-dialog pops up twice, no matter from where I call it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure on how to read the call stacks but I think the second time it is being called from the Application.exit() method

Comment: There is a FormClosingEventArgs e parameter in the form closing event handler, set `e.Cancel = false` before the line 'Application.Exit()' and verify that the messagebox comes only once. You can also check e.CloseReason property in debug mode to get a value that indicates why the form is being closed.

Comment: Also, I think if u set `e.Cancel = false;`, there should not be a need to write `Application.Exit()`. Pls verify..

Comment: Putting `e.Cancel = false` before `Application.Exit()` did not change anything. But using only `e.Cancel = false` did the trick! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't forget to call `base.OnFormClosing(e)` in your method otherwise the `FormClosing` event won't fire and you might have other issues because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use events instead of overriding:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing (object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show ("My App", "Really quit?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                // close connection
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```